# Loop for Python code that simulates/automates keyboard presses. How do I allow it to continuously loop without breaking once CTRL C is pressed?

Tags: python, excel, automation

SO basically I wrote this very basic code that will be used to automate a labour intensive part of my job. This involves copying and pasting lines from an excel file by shift clicking down 6 times, copying, alt tabbing to SAP, pasting, shift F1 to add more search lines, and then alt tabbing back to excel (BEGIN LOOPING HERE) where ill have to click down 6 times AND THEN shift click down 7 times, copy, alt tab, paste, shift F1, alt tab.

I have the basic code for the key presses in but cannot figure out how to loop. Can someone help out?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

time.sleep(5)

    
#Shift click down 6 total items
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)

time.sleep(0.25)
#Copy 7 seleced cells
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('c')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)

time.sleep(0.25)
#switch tabs (to SAP from Excel)
keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)

time.sleep(0.25)
#Paste 7 selected cells onto SAP
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('v')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)

#Allow for further cells to be added to search "shift F1"
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.F1)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
keyboard.release(Key.F1)

time.sleep(0.25)
#switch tabs (Back to Excel from SAP)
keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)

#BEGIN LOOP HERE
#Shift click down 13 total items
#this first part is to get back to the end of the first row of selected cells
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)

#this part is to start selecting new cells to be copied and pasted
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)

time.sleep(0.25)
#Copy 7 seleced cells
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('c')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)

time.sleep(0.25)
#switch tabs (to SAP from Excel)
keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)

time.sleep(0.25)
#Paste 7 selected cells onto SAP
keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
keyboard.press('v')
keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)

#Allow for further cells to be added to search "shift F1"
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.F1)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
keyboard.release(Key.F1)

time.sleep(0.25)
#switch tabs (Back to Excel from SAP)
keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)

#END LOOP HERE
```

Comment: If you are going to write code, write code that takes a CSV file exported from Excel, transforms that into another CSV file (or similar), then import that file into SAP, rather than trying to simulate the physical steps you take to perform the task right now.

Comment: Computers are good at processing data: let it do that instead of simulating a person using a computer.

Comment: I can't import a CSV file to excel for this specific task. the only way to do it (from what I have seen) is to do it manually by searching specific invoice numbers. This would also act as a multi took for other process I'd need  for work.

Comment: @gawron98 Is there a chance you could share an example excel file, and then the desired output/changes?

Comment: About your question: Any python tutorial will cover loops. To do something exactly 13 times, use `for x in range(13): ... `. But I agree with the others: if you can make the effort to learn how to use a library that can read Excel files, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: For Pauls request, the excel file contains 17000 lines of invoices that would need to be copied over onto SAP. In SAP however you can only copy 7 lines at a time and so this is why I would like to automate it. I am very new to coding so bare with me!

Comment: @gawron98 It certainly makes sense that you'd want to automate this task. That being said, writing a script to copy-paste the rows into SAP isn't the way to go. If I'm understanding you correctly, all you're trying to do is copy/migrate these 17000 excel rows into SAP? I should probably mention that I have no idea what SAP is. What file-formats does it support?

Comment: I very much doubt that the *only* way to interface with SAP is to paste a small, fixed number of lines manually, one group at a time. This is *definitely* an XY problem. You want to know how to import data into SAP, and you are assuming that the only way to do that is via manual copy-and-pasting.